# Reduce number of calls to stringResource()

Tags: android, kotlin, android-resources, android-jetpack-compose

In the past it was a costly operation to call `resources.getString()` or something.
Is it still true in terms of jetpack compose and how to avoid call to `stringResource()` every time the compose function is recomposed/called? How one can overload the function so that you don't have to call `stringResource()` for each function call?

For example I have a compose function

```
@Composable
fun ButtonText(
    text: String,
) {
    Text(
        text = text.uppercase(Locale.getDefault()),
        textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
        style = Typography.button
    )
}
```

and I call it from another compose function, but here let's use just a preview

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun ButtonTextPreview() {
    Surface {
        ButtonText(text = stringResource(id = R.string.button_example))
    }
}
```

As I understand it every time an outer compose function will be recomposed the `ButtonText()` will be called and in there `stringResource()` will be called too.

Answer (score -1):

To avoid these unnecessary recompostions, your best bet is state-hoisting. Refer to the docs for an in-depth explanation but the solution in this case would be to receive the string as an argument instead of calling it in-Composable. Hence, it won't be re3quired to fetch it over and over when this Composable recomposes. Just hoist it all the way up to where it's the most efficient.

```
@Composable
fun ButtonTextPreview(txt: String) {
    Surface {
        ButtonText(text = txt)
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't call stringResource inside remember: Composable calls are not allowed inside the calculation parameter of inline fun <T> remember(crossinline calculation: () -> TypeVariable(T)): TypeVariable(T)

Comment: @LXJ thanks for the correction, I must have posted this while I was just starting to learn Compose and failed to realise that `stringResource` is a Composable function. I'll edit that right away.

Comment: Ok apparently it had nothing to do with `remember` in the first place.